# Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to migrate from Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2.x and getting below error

Error:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
Jun 01, 2022 5:57:50 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport shutdown
INFO: Shutting down ExecutorService 'ucThreadPoolExecutor'
[INFO ] [6458] 2022-06-01 17:57:50,767 [main] CacheManager-425 - Shutting down the executors on all the regions...
[ERROR] [6459] 2022-06-01 17:57:50,768 [main] UnifiedCompareEngineApplication-52 - Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[com.XXXX1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <artifactId>xxx-maven-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <name>xxx</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.xxx.xxApplication</start-class>
        <spring-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <spring-boot-version>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
        <version.build-helper-maven-plugin>1.7</version.build-helper-maven-plugin> -->
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>
                        spring-boot-starter-logging
                    </artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
        <artifactId>jconn</artifactId>
        <version>3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Test cases dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                  <version>2.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is currently still trying to use the log4j version 1.x `Level` class.
You can change this to Log4j version 2.x with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And you have already correctly removed the default logger:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Sources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging

If you then still have other libraries that depend on log4j version 1.x that you can't upgrade, there is also a bridge available:

- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you if things works for me